# Merging git repositories and preserving history

Tags: git, git-subtree

I've been using a symfony1 plugin repository in a project repository, using [git-subtree](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh), but I can't always see my history.

Basically, the plugin project has a composer.json file 
I merged the plugin under the `plugins/MyPlugin` subtree.

When I do `git log`, I can see the history. However, when do `git log -p plugins/MyPlugin/composer.json` or `git log plugins/MyPlugin/composer.json`, I only see a merge commit. Why ?

But maybe subtree isn't really the right tool. What I want to do is forget completely about the plugin repository and pretend that its commits actually happened in the project repository, modifying files in the plugins/MyPlugin directory.

**EDIT** Ok, I solved my problem by rewriting the plugin history with a `filter-branch`, and merging the result in the project repository. Still the first question remains. For science.

Answer (score 0):

A single merge commit isn't so bad. Use --squash to avoid flooding your history with the library history.

As for git log, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218022/1270965